# CSS fix or CSS reset for all websites

Tags: html, css

I have made a small popup window that shows up at the bottom of the page (like a recommendation system). But whenever I embed my script to any of the client's website, it disturbs my `CSS`. Like the `CSS` which is on the client's website overshadows my `CSS` and this causes me to fix my `CSS` for each client. Is there a fix that I will have to install on my code?

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Give the popup window an `id` attribute and only apply styling on that ID.

Comment: What @JamesDonnelly says. Prefix the id if you want to be extra super sure it's unique.

Comment: i am applying styling based on id's

Comment: @DivyanshuAbhichandani if that is the case then your popup's CSS should never affect your main page's CSS. If your popup is being given styling from your client's website, simply increase the specificity on your popup's selectors.

Comment: An example of your CSS would help us to see how you are currently specifying your properties.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP's problem is the opposite, that the client's generic css styling things like `div` or `span` is the problem. What you could do is take a [css reset library](http://www.cssreset.com/), and edit it's code to only apply to elements within your popup by nesting it in an id selector.

Comment: when i inspect element on the layout, i can see that some of the css elements on the main website disturbs my code. Like p,h,button tags etc.. I do have a Prefix id before each element in my CSS @JamesDonnelly

Comment: @LcLk can u please give an example.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to overlapping `CSS` properties of client's and your newly developed. I recommend you to inspect element of google chrome's very nice feature. You can individually identify your overlapping properties. If this is too much complex. Like James commented give a `new id` to your pop-up menu, which will separate your pop-up `CSS` from all other components on your web page

Answer (score 0):

On of the ways I heard about is Shadow Dom, and in this article it describe it and at the beginning of the article he listed the problem in brief: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/

> But there is a fundamental problem that makes widgets built out of
>   HTML and JavaScript hard to use: The DOM tree inside a widget isn’t
>   encapsulated from the rest of the page. This lack of encapsulation
>   means your document stylesheet might accidentally apply to parts
>   inside the widget; your JavaScript might accidentally modify parts
>   inside the widget; your IDs might overlap with IDs inside the widget;
>   and so on.

Else which I did my self long time ago is: to name all your ids, classes with a special names for example 'mywebsite.myclass' this may minimize the issue. and I saw this way is used by many bookmarklets which import html,css and javascript to user opened page.

Answer (score 0):

"All browsers" is a lot of browsers :P

CSS is going to get interesting soon thanks to shadow DOM.  You are going to be able to create a web component that is completely isolated, DOM and CSS, from the rest of the document, which is exactly what you want.
Obviously, it's not in place in al browsers (only in Chrome at the time of me writing this).  Meanwhile, this is what I would do:

- Use shadow DOM components if available
- Anyway, manually name-space everything you use (CSS classes, JavaScript, etc)
- Try to use custom elements for everything. (that way, there's less risk of your e.g. `<h2>`s being styled by outer CSSs)
- As a last resource, use very specific selectors (look up CSS specificity), and use `!important`.  Just to be clear: never do this routinely!

Most of that stuff will fail for some value of "All browsers".  You'll have to compromise somewhere, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can reset your div styles.
Something like this:

```
div.your-popup * {
 /* your reset */
}
```

And try to set !important to styles or put them inline.

In addition create unique class names that no one can override it.

P.S. http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: `!important` is unnecessary. Just increase selector specificity.